# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: in angular9

Tags: angular

> i use angular9+ version ,I give all paths in my router module but i
>   get this type of error
>   core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'mystore.component' Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'mystore.component'
>       at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4396)
>       at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4360)
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
>       at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
>       at zone-evergreen.js:860
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41632)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
>
> mystore.component.html

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

> menu.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-success navbar-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class=" nav-link"  routerLink="/mystore.component" routerLinkActive="active">MyStore</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class=" nav-link"   routerLink="/admin.component" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class=" nav-link"   routerLink="/users.component"  routerLinkActive="active">User</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="dropdown">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Product
    </button> 
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="#">Grosery</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="#">Vegetable</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="#">Cusmatic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> app.routeing.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
    import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
    import { MystoreComponent } from './mystore/mystore.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo:'mystore',pathMatch: 'full'},
        { path: 'admin.component', component: AdminComponent },
        { path: 'users.component', component: UsersComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting to `mystore` and yet there isn't any `mystore` path defined. Also in the component template you're referring it to as `mystore.component` instead. You need to settle on a single path name. Try the following

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'mystore.component', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'admin.component', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'users.component', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'mystore.component', component: UsersComponent }
];
```

Comment: I do in this way but it cannot work.it open my users componentpage as default. I want when i press localhost:4200/or any one open my site it will show my mystore component page as default.i have usercomponent page and user component page but i want mystore as default page not users page

Comment: I've edited the answer to move the empty path to top. See if it works for you.

Comment: it doesnot  matter you declare empty path at first or last I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

it ever happened to me once. i hava dig down to this forum to see the answer but i have no luck.

in my case, i can't bind any routerLink to event handler but if i write down the desired path to url i can access it.

example

```
localhost:4200/dashboard
```

since i see your proj is not that complicated yet, i advise you to generate the new one!